# Is it possible to build/compile ios, windows 8 and windows 7 apps on linux?

Tags: android, ios, linux, windows-8

I am building a cross platform app. It will be built for windows 8, IOS, android and windows 7.

**Problem**: 
On the server I have 4 different code bases. 1 for windows 8, 1 for windows 7, 1 for android and 1 for Ios. With the help of a back-end and some scripts am going change the code base. So every time there is a change apps need to be built/compiled on the server. 
(Am using phonegap)

Can we build/compile these apps on a linux server ? If no what is the best solution?

Do I need to get separate servers for different apps ? ios(ios server), windows 8(windows 8 server), windows 7(windows 7 server) and android(linux server) ?

**Edits**: I know we need windows8 and ios for their apps. Am going to test it on these OS in development environment and then update it on the server for my clients. After that they want to change the content in the apps. For which am creating a backend, which will with help of certain scripts update the code base with new data. 
Now these apps have to built in the production environment there itself. i.e it needs to be automated.

Comment: **NOTE:** A-Live's comment below [Phonegap getting started](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/guide_getting-started_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20Guides).  The question's title is misleading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Beware**: Probably wrong answer; deleted/undeleted it because of comments. **PhoneGap** looks complex!

> Can we build/compile these apps on a linux server?

Yes you can.  Whether that is sane or not is another issue.

However, you **can** get a `mingw` cross compiler on the Linux machine.  This is capable of building binaries for Windows 7 and 8; I have absolutely done this.  Also, it is certainly possible to make an *iOS* cross compiler for Linux.  The issue is that you need all the headers and libraries.  Ie, you need a complete *shadow development directory* on Linux.

None of this is simple.  If you have Ubuntu/Debian, I am pretty sure that it supplies some [*mingw* packages](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=mingw&searchon=names&suite=stable&section=all).

This question skirts the bounds of being program related.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Isn't this a genuine problem?. Why has this question been downvoted ?

Comment: @Akash Deshpande It is maybe better asked on a0nther forum, like super user, and I see many [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516690/is-it-possible-to-compile-windows-binaries-on-a-linux-machine?rq=1) under related links to the side (now that I looked); people who cross-compile are usually programmers.  I answered because of the other answer which seems incorrect to me.

Comment: I wonder how much time will it take to get at least the first functional system (not to mention its permanent needs for support), if it actually appear to be more effective than a way to buy a single mac mini and follow all the official documentation.

Comment: @A-Live  I made no claims that this is the easiest route.  It maybe if you only have a console app and use the *standard library*.  If you are using GUI tool kits, BOOST, or whatever.  The poster hasn't even stated what language he is using.

Comment: He's gonna use [Phonegap](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/guide_getting-started_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20Guides) which I believe relies on the standard dev-tools for each platform (like Xcode for iOs, SDK tools for Android, VS for Win 8). At least that's what the documentation is saying.

Comment: @artlessnoise I don't really think the question is off-topic for SO. Talking about using (highly) programmer-specific tools is very much allowed as per the FAQ. (Now it might have other problems, but it's on-topic.)

Comment: @A-Live I see; I guess only you and [jcesar](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1351469/jcesar) saw this.  I have no idea what *phonegap* was.  The questions title is completely wrong (or at least misleading).  I answered that.  The *phonegap* requirements are to run simulators, etc under Eclipse.  I still think you can *compile/build* on Linux?

Comment: Even if he can compile in linux, he can't upload iOS apps to the store without a mac. Now there are CLI tools to compile phonegap without IDES, but on iOS you still need xcode comand line tools

Comment: @jcesar I up voted your answer.  I don't think mine is completely wrong.  I understand the complexity now.  It was easy to gloss over the *phone gap* in the question and then it seems like he is asking something completely different.  Also all the OS tags are kind of useless (and mis-leading).

Comment: I upvoted yours too, I didn't know about mingw. Phonegap doesn't add complexity because it has to be compiled too. If it is possible to compile an iOS app, it has to be possible to compile a phonegap app.

Answer (score 1):

You need a mac for iOS and windows 8 for windows 8 apps

Comment: And you can build Android apps either with OS X, Windows or Linux. See [Getting Started Guides](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/guide_getting-started_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20Guides), each section has listed requirements.