# How to compile C++ Linux TCP Socket programming code for Windows platform without modifying source code?

Tags: c, sockets, cross-compiling

I created programs transferring information between client and server by C++ TCP socket programming and compile and run it on Linux. But how to compile the source code to windows executable for Windows user clients?

I've tried using

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ ...
```

to compile. But the it fails for not find these files.

```
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
```

I know Microsoft provides windows programming APIs, but it will require a lot of adjustment of codes. How to correctly set a cross-compiler to compile it properly for Windows, without having to modify codes?

In theory, C++/C should be a high level language and is not platform-specific.

The solution here doesn't work for me (codes containing TCP sockets).
[How to compile C code in Linux to run on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44670209/how-to-compile-c-code-in-linux-to-run-on-windows)

Comment: *"C++/C should be a high level language and is not platform-specific."* - the language isn't platform-specific. But socket APIs are not part of the language itself.

Comment: WSL2, cygwin, a VM, a lot of `#ifdef WIN32`/`#else`/`#endif` blocks to conditionally use winsock instead of POSIX headers and apis...

Comment: The correct solution is to add a bunch of `#ifdef _WIN32`s to your code (not `WIN32`, btw), or to use a wrapper library that does it for you. There's also Cygwin, that might be able to compile your code as is, but A - I don't know if it's possible to cross-compile with it, and B - I'd argue that it shouldn't be a development target of new cross-platform software, but only a way of porting old non-portable software from Linux.